# I cant fetch data from odoo calendar using intent of dialogflow and webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, odoo

I want to list the event of odoo calendar in my chatbot created in dialogflow and using webhook.

This is my code :

```
function GetEventOdoo(agent) {
    let username =agent.parameters.username;
    var odooResult;

    var odoo = new Odoo({
        url: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        port: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        db: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        username: 'xxxxxxxx@example.com',
        password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });

    odooResult = JSON.stringify(odoo);

    console.log('odooResult!!!:' + odooResult );

    odoo.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('connection error: '+ JSON.stringify(err)); }
        console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');
        var inParams = [];
        inParams.push([]); //where conditions
        inParams.push(['name']); //fields
        inParams.push(0); //offset
        inParams.push(5); //limit
        var params = [];
        params.push(inParams);
        odoo.execute_kw('calendar.event', 'search_read', params, function (err, value){
            if (err) { return console.log(err); }
            console.log(value);

        });
    })

    return  odooResult += JSON.stringify(value)
      // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
        .then(res => {

            const launchData = res.data;

           agent.add(`Odoo event is: ${launchData[0].ID}  `);
            console.log(`Odoo event is: ${launchData[0].ID}  `);



        });

}
```

I can't connect with odoo to list data, i try out of dialogflow and works good, but here it's not working , maybe i have to correct the function to list this data from webhook to dialogflow.

Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

```
Error: No handler for requested intent
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:327:29)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:118:9)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:49:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Edited:

- I just uploaded my code like this*

  ```
     function findeventlist(username) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const odoo = new Odoo({
              url: 'http://sssss',
              port: '80',
              db: 'ssss',
              username: 'sssssssss',
              password: 'sssssssss'
          });
          //odooResult = JSON.stringify(odoo);
          odoo.connect(function (err) {
              if (err) {
                  return console.log(err);
              }
              console.log('findeventlist Connected to Odoo server.');
              const params = [];

              params.push([]);
              params.push(['name']);
              params.push(0);
              params.push(5);
              params.push([params]);
              odoo.execute_kw('calendar.event', 'search_read', params, function (err, value) {
                  if (err) {
                      return console.log(err);
                  }
                  console.log('Result: ', value);
                  resolve.send(JSON.stringify(value));


              })
                  .catch(error => {
                      console.log(error);
                      reject(error);
                  });
          });
      });
  }


  function GetEventOdoo(agent) {

      let username = agent.parameters.username;
      console.log("GetEventOdoo");
      return findeventlist().then(() => {
          agent.add(`Event: ${username}, `);
      }).catch(() => {
          agent.add(`  `);
      });

  }
  ```

Error is : Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted.

Comment: Can you update your question to indicate if you are doing this using the Built-in Fulfillment Editor in Firebase, or elsewhere? It also isn't clear if `GetEventOdoo()` is the Intent Hander, or how you're calling it if not. (There are lines that don't make sense in it - you are calling `.then()` on `JSON.stringify()`, which isn't a Thennable.

Comment: I'm using webhook javascript , GetEventOdoo is intent name and function name...i'm new and i need help to fix the code please

Comment: Please update your question to show how `GetEventOdoo()` is called or registered.

Comment: is called by intent in dialogflow and this intent call the same function in webhook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up how you use Promises with other methods. This is certainly not returning what you expect, likely causing the response to not be sent back, and could be causing other issues such as memory leaks.

For example, in a few places in your code, inside the Promise, you have

```
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
```

All this does is quit out of the Promise without calling either `resolve()` or `reject()`, but it has returned that Promise to the Intent dispatcher, which is waiting for it to either resolve or reject, which never happens.

To fix this, instead of returning the console log (?), you should explicitly call `reject()` in these cases. So your code might look something like

```
        if (err) {
            reject( err );
        }
```

This is only this complicated because you are wrapping calls to odoo in the Promise yourself. I don't know which library you're using, but you may wish to use one that works with Promises natively. For example, the [odoo-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo-api) library lets you write things such as

```
function findeventlist(){
  return odoo
      .connect({
          database: 'unicorn',
          username: 'foo',
          password: 'bar'
      })
      .then(client => {
          return client.searchRead('product.product', [['list_price', '>', '50']], {limit: 1});
      })
      .then(products => {
          console.log(products);
          //=> [{list_price: 52, name: 'Unicorn'}]
          agent.add( `I found ${products.length} results` );
      });
};
```

without having to create or manage the Promise yourself. Using this library would even let you use async/await in the more recent versions of node, so this could even be written as something like (untested)

```
async function findeventlist(){
  const client = await odoo.connect( connectionParameters );
  const products = await client.searchRead('product.product', [['list_price', '>', '50']], {limit: 1});
  console.log( products );
  agent.add( `I found ${products.length} results` );
}
```